# How to move and enter folders and subfolders in python

Tags: python, file

i have a dataset and one folder and in this folder i have a few subfolder in them there is audio file i need to move on the whole subfolders and get the file and the path , i using python
osomeone has idea?

**folder:** dataset -> **folders**: rock,regge,hiphop,classic,disco,jazz,pop,blues,country,metal -> **files:** "name".wav
i need to enter each folder and get the file and path.
i have 100 files in folder.

i dont try nothing because i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `os.walk`

```
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file    
        if filepath.endswith(".wav"):
            print(filepath)
```